# How I get Data from th SQLite Database to a EditText?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-activity, android-edittext

hi i want to get data from the sqlite database. I want to use a method to load data in my Edittext.

```
private void ladeDaten(String tbname,String fach)
    {
        String select = "SELECT info FROM "+tbname+" WHERE name='"+fach+"'";

        String info = ""; // how I can 

        ((EditText)(findViewById(R.id.txtContacto))).setText(info);
    }
```

What can I do?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html is a good tutorial for Sqlite.

Comment: An example of what you looking for can be found in 
<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015731/android-sqlite-example
<br>

Comment: Where does `fach` come from? Alway keep [little Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for you :

```
public int GetDeptID(String Dept)
  {
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

   Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+colDeptID+" as _id FROM "+deptTable+" WHERE "+colDeptName+"=?",
new String []{Dept});
   c.moveToFirst();
   return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));

  }
```

Read more here : http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-sqlite-database/

**ITS ONLY EXAMPLE**