# Database inside of Android

Tags: android, sql, database

I wonder whether there is a way to store data in like a MySQL inside of Android OS.
I have more complex data that I need to save and I dont think SharedPreferences will work.
Is there a predefined way, and how can I access it? Is it in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

well there is SQLite database which is very light weight database to store data in android..

**Edit** 
when you start working with SQLite on android you should not mix it up with MySQL or PHPMyAdmin or any other complex database structure. SQLite is just about storing some information on your device internally and accessing it for some purpose. It is not used for complex database tasks that you do in PhpMyAdmin.

Rather you should visit the links given by @Vee in the answer.

Comment: can I see the database structure anywhere? like is there something similar to phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Philip you can try using sqlite browser tool for android db.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is. On Android each application has own place for database (SQLite). Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html
for further details. It's really easy to maintain

Comment: can I see the database structure anywhere? like is there something similar to phpmyadmin?

Comment: Rather not. It is stored and managed internally. SQLite on Android is rather just about storing in tables than more complex administration.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there is SQLite

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015731/android-sqlite-example) is a question asking for examples.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) is the SQLiteDatabase class. Goo start point.

Comment: can I see the database structure anywhere? like is there something similar to phpmyadmin?