# Send data to server and delete the data that are successfully sent

Tags: android, server

I want to send the data from the sqlite database in android to the server and delete those data from the database that have been reached to the server successfully. I have successfully written the code to send data to the server. But could not delete the data form database. How to know which data is reached to the server.

```
package com.example.income;


import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.*;

public class Background extends IntentService
{   

public Background()
{
    super("This is the simple background class");   
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    Log.v("message","This is simple background service");
    Db db =new Db(Background.this,"simple",null,4);
    Cursor c= db.getData();

    if( c.moveToFirst())
    {
        List<Map<String, String>> contacts = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        do
        {
            String num,dater;
            int integer;
            integer=c.getInt (c.getColumnIndex(Base.Identifier));
            num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Base.CONTACTS));
            dater =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Base.DATE));
            Map<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
            contact.put("date", dater);
            contact.put("contact", num);
            contact.put("id",String.valueOf(integer));
            contacts.add(contact);
      }
        while (c.moveToNext());

        try
        {
            sendData(contacts);             


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
   }

public void sendData(List<Map<String, String>> contacts) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException 
{
    Log.v("Let's C","Will it go here?");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.115/android.php");
        Log.v("p","this");
        Log.d("Contacts", Integer.toString(contacts.size()));

        JSONArray array= new JSONArray(contacts);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forward",array.toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response=  httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

        String result =EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i =0;i<obj.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json=obj.getJSONObject(i);
            String success =json.getString("id");
            Log.i("success ",success);  
        }

/*  
    Runtime runtime1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = runtime1.exec("ping -c 8 www.google.com"); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String input;

    while((input=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        Log.i("message",input);
    }*/


}
}
```

I want to implement this as soon as data is sent to server.

Comment: You are using "String result". What is the value for result?

Comment: When you successfully send data to the server , call delete method of table where you need to pass  the id of the data which you want to delete.

Comment: mine problem is that i could not get the id of the successfully send data i tried from httpresponse but it didnot help

Comment: Return some acknowledge message with all the records id which are received by the server

Comment: You can also delete data by some unique value stored in database

Comment: ["{id=1, date=1442394480, contact=9843241699}"]  this is my response message. From this how can i get only id value so that i would delete the database record base on this id reference

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that compares the value of sqlite data you send to the server through JSON object/array and return a flag. If it is successful then delete local data, if not try resending your data again.

This link might help you achieve your goal.

[how to send data to server from android when no internet is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360034/how-to-send-data-to-server-from-android-when-no-internet-is-available)