# Store JSON object temporarily and POST to Volley when Internet is available

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley

I am using `Volley` in application. I am sending data using `REST` Api to server. This is the JSON `POST` request to Server.

```
private void add() {
        String NetworkStatus = biz.fyra.bookapp.utils.NetworkStatus.checkConnection(getContext());
        if (NetworkStatus.equals("false")) {
            alert.noInternetAlert(getActivity());
        } else {
            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            try {
                info.put("name", full_name);
                info.put("phone", foodie_contact);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ApiUrls.ADD, info, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
            };
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        }
    }
```

If Internet is available I am able to POST data to server. But If Internet is not available I need to temporarily store this JSON object somewhere and when Internet is available I need to POST all JSON objects to server that were stored locally. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried using a `JobScheduler`?

Comment: No. Please provide me suitable link for reference.

Comment: Please see: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26360936/9763253) and this: [JobScheduler Example Video](https://youtu.be/3EQWmME-hNA)

Comment: you can store json object in singleton class. It will store value only till app is running.

Comment: Hi @Satyam , on error listener store the input json in database and write listener for internet connectivity , if user comes to online from offline then push all the data to server

Comment: Save data in shared preferences, if you are getting some response against your posting i.e if you get success from there, then after getting success remove from shared preference. If is that your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Achieving this you have to follow these steps.

1. Check if the internet is connected.
2. If the internet is connected send the call.
3. If the internet is not connected you you can convert the Json to string and save it 
   in Shared preferences or DataBase.
4. Then you have to create a broadcast reciver for checking the internet connections and
5. when ever you get the message for active internet you need to send the pending data 
   to server.

**UPDATE**
For creating a broadcast reciever

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
        Log.d("Network Available ", "Flag No 1");
    }
}
```

}

And then in your Application tag within Menifest file Add Intent Filter

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Let me know if you need assistance in following these steps.

Comment: Can you please Assist me for checking when Internet is available using Broadcast Receiver ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You will receive the broadcast is onreceive method and  then you can perform the desired operation.