# Best way to create a data file in Android

Tags: android, database, accessible

What is the best way to create a data file in Android for saving data like usernames, configuration, and other variables accessible only by the Application?

Is there an official way to do this?

Comment: You open up a file and do file IO via the normal Java classes.  Small bits of key/value configuration can be put in shared preferences.  And of course relational data can be put in an SQLite db.

Answer (score 3):

Android has some ways for save data.

Configurations are usually handled by Android [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).
Where you can save your settings, doing something like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("silentMode", true);
editor.commit();
```

For recover data, just do something like this:

```
// Restore preferences
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
```

If you want to save more advanced type of data(make relationships between data, index, validations, avoid repeating), is better to use a [database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for it, and android provides an api to handle this using sqlite databases through [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class.

More detailed example about android database you can find in this stackoverflow question:
[Android SQLite Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015731/android-sqlite-example)