# Trying to view contents of sqlite file - adb no such file or directory android

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

Whenever I run the following line

```
  adb -d shell "run-as com.package.name ls /data/user/0/com.package.name/databases/"
```

I get the following error

```
 /data/user/0/com.package.name/databases/ no such file or directory
```

This is how I'm creating the database

```
   public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String DatabaseName) {
    super(context, DatabaseName+".db", null, 1);

    this.context      = context;
    this.DatabaseName = DatabaseName+".db";
    Log.d(TAG, "DB: " + DatabaseName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Path: " + context.getDatabasePath(this.DatabaseName).toString());


}
```

The Log cat however displays the following

```
 Path: /data/user/0/com.package.name/databases/test1.db
```

Signaling that the database has been created. Why is the command prompt telling me no such file or directory exists?

Hours ago I entered the line

```
   adb shell pm clear com.package.name
```

As I wanted to delete the previous databases that I found on the device. But when I started to have problems I simply uninstalled using

```
  adb uninstall com.package.name
```

However, I'm still experiencing problems. My overall main goal is to simply view the contents of my databases for development purposes. I currently have a Nexus 5 (Android Version 6.0.1 unrooted phone) connected to a PC.

Does anyone have an idea on what the problem might be?

Comment: You might not have permission as the adb shell to enter the directory in order to `ls` it, regardless of the existence of the actual file

Comment: @cricket_007 The tool you recommended is great. However, I still can't see my databases Under WebSQL. I have the following in my onCreate function in the Application class:   Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);    It seems other aspects of the framework does work as I can see my shared preferences  under local storage.

Comment: Did you setup the application class within the manifest? I've not used Stetho, so I don't exactly know how it works

Comment: Actually never mind. The problem was I wasn't writing anything to the database. So a database and table were not created. Thanks again for recommending the tool.

Answer (score 0):

you can see how to create database in android studio in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12015869/2621857),

then for pulling the database out of your application:

1: run your application in your emulator 
2: in android studio top menu  open Tools --> Android --> Android Device Monitor 
3: in the right section of the Android Device Monitor  you can find the file explorer with out using any shell script . 
4: in data folder find your package name then pull out the db