# resend data to server when connection is back

Tags: android, database, retrofit, rx-java, broadcast

I want to send data to server with `retrofit` library .

And I want to know how to resend my data to server when network is back

```
 public void sendPost(String title, String body) {
    mpiService.savePost(title, body, 1).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse(response.body().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
        }
    });
}
```

I know I should create database and use `broadcast` to check status
I want to know how I can store data to database with data field or `jSONArray`?

Please help me with database creation

Answer (score 0):

You can use **realm** for your local database. It is easy to use, faster, well documented and support various platform. For more details visit their official website: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

**1) SQLiteOpenHeleper:**

You can store data into SQLite database with SQLiteOpenHelper class.

for a simple implementation watch this link :
[Android SQLite Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015731/android-sqlite-example)

**2) Room Library:** (Recommended)

This is a great library written by google that provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow for more robust database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite.

for a simple implemantation watch this links:
[A Beginner’s Guide to the Room Persistence Library](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/room-sqlite-beginner-tutorial-2e725e47bfab)
[Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

**3) Shared Prefrences:**
If you have a simple data you can store it via Shared Prefrences. it is not a database though. Shared Preferences allow you to save and retrieve data in the form of key,value pair inside xml files in device data folder.

for a simple implementation watch this:
[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

**4) Realm:**
Realm is a mobile database and a replacement for SQLite. Realm is not using SQLite as it’s engine. Instead it has own C++ core and aims to provide a mobile-first alternative to SQLite.

You can learn it with this link:
[How to use Realm for Android like a champ, and how to tell if you’re doing it wrong](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149)

**5) ETC**
There is some other types like File (read/write) and greenDao. You can learn them by just simple googling :)