# Can't insert Data on SQLite Database Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have tried to insert Student Dethasails on my Student Table Data. But this error is shown:
*Error inserting STUDENT_ROLL=1 STUDENT_NAME=D _CID=4
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: STUDENT_TABLE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO STUDENT_TABLE(STUDENT_ROLL,STUDENT_NAME,_CID) VALUES (?,?,?)*

This is  my code:
Declare Table:-

```
public static final String STUDENT_TABLE_NAME = "STUDENT_TABLE";
public static final String S_ID = "_SID";
public static final String STUDENT_NAME_KEY = "STUDENT_NAME";
public static final String STUDENT_ROLL_KEY = "STUDENT_ROLL";

public static final String CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + STUDENT_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                S_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                C_ID + " LONG , " +
                STUDENT_NAME_KEY + " VARCHAR(255), " +
                STUDENT_ROLL_KEY + " INTEGER , " +
                " FOREIGN KEY (" + C_ID + ") REFERENCES " + CLASS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +C_ID+")" +");";

public static final String DROP_STUDENT_TABLE = " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + STUDENT_TABLE_NAME;
public static final String SELECT_STUDENT_TABLE = "SELECT * FROM " + STUDENT_TABLE_NAME;
```

Add Student Method for adding Students. c_id is a foreign key.

```
long addStudent(long c_id, String studentName, int studentRoll){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(STUDENT_NAME_KEY,studentName);
    values.put(STUDENT_ROLL_KEY,studentRoll);
    values.put(C_ID, c_id);
    try{
        long s_id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(STUDENT_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        return s_id;
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The error is clear: *no such table*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12015869/8133524 follow this

Answer (score 2):

The problem here as indicated in the logs is that the table doesn't exists. You created the sqlite statement for creation of the table but I think you didn't execute it from anywhere. You must execute the sqlite statement in your Database helper class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
  database.execSQL(CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE);
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#DbHelper)

Answer (score 1):

you created the query to create your table but it has not been executed anywhere, you just have to execute it before performing an insert

```
  database.execSQL(CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE);
```